# No ajax call made in production mode, no HITs in varnish

Tags: magento2.3, varnish

Please correct me if I'm wrong: According to the explanations on the web, magento should be loading pages using AJAXs and some of those calls should be cached by the varnish.

I successfully configured varnish. When in developer mode, pages are loaded by AJAX calls, some of which are HITs as expected. However, when I switch to production mode, no ajax calls made, whole page is loaded as a single html, thus I am not getting any HITs.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me fix this issue.

Developer mode:
[image]

Production mode:
[image]

Comment: can you give some screenshots or code where you have problems ?

Comment: @ParulThakkar I've added screenshots

Comment: Is the css and js working fine or you're getting 404 on them?

Comment: any console js errors?

Comment: @VivekKumar They're working fine. I filtered html and xhr requests for clarity.

Comment: @Marius No errors, page works just fine in production mode too - albeit without ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

1. The assumption I made about ajax calls being cached was wrong. The
   page itself should be cached.
2. There was a bug in this file, preventing the page from being cached:
   app/design/frontend/Codazon/fastest/fashion/Magento_Captcha/layout/default.xml

   This bug is fixed in later versions.